# keyboardWillShow how to apply to only 1 textView in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

We have an app which looks like this:

[App here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3Z5I.png)

We have `UITextViews` in the top and in the bottom of the view and I had been asking for some help in order to move the screen up when the `keyboard` appears.

It actually works perfect but I'm wondering how to apply this only for the `UITextView` (`textViewInteriorDos`) in the bottom of the screen, which was touching the keyboard before. 
How to apply correctly the `if/ else` statement in this methods guys??

The top `UITextView` is not covered with the keyboard, so we don't need it.

```
class viewControllerCuatro: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var textViewInteriorUno: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var textViewInteriorDos: UITextView!

override func viewDidLoad() {


    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Atrás", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: nil, action: nil)


    **NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: self.view.window)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: self.view.window)**




}


    func keyboardWillShow(sender: NSNotification) 
{
        // 1
        let userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject] = sender.userInfo!
        // 2
        let keyboardSize: CGSize = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey]!.CGRectValue.size
        let offset: CGSize = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]!.CGRectValue.size
        // 3
        if keyboardSize.height == offset.height {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
                self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
            })
        } else {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
                self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height - offset.height
            })
            }


    }
func keyboardWillHide(sender: NSNotification) {
            let userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject] = sender.userInfo!
            let keyboardSize: CGSize = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey]!.CGRectValue.size
            self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height
        }
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: self.view.window)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: self.view.window)
    }

 override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    if textViewInteriorUno.text == ""  || textViewInteriorUno.text.isEmpty == true || textViewInteriorDos.text == "" || textViewInteriorDos.text.isEmpty == true {


        textViewInteriorUno.resignFirstResponder()


        textViewInteriorDos.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    else{

        self.textViewInteriorUno.resignFirstResponder()

        self.textViewInteriorDos.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}

func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool{

    var shouldReplace = true // For most cases, return true, only modify if we have a special case

    // If the textView is 'textViewInteriorUno'
    if textView.isEqual(textViewInteriorUno) {

    let newLength = textViewInteriorUno.text.utf16.count + text.utf16.count - range.length
    shouldReplace = newLength <= 12           // will be true if the length is <= 12

    }

    else if textView.isEqual(textViewInteriorDos) {

    let newLength = textViewInteriorDos.text.utf16.count + text.utf16.count - range.length
    shouldReplace = newLength < 13 // Will be true if the length > 6


    }

    return shouldReplace
}
```

Comment: Did you try to call isFirstResponder() on the UITextView? I think it should return true in case it is the one being edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it can help you as below

prepare:

```
@IBOutlet weak var textSkillSearch: UITextView!

@IBOutlet weak var textWillSearch: UITextView!
```

1. mark notification to add observer

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(MainViewController.textViewDidBeginEditing(_:)), name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil);
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(MainViewController.keyboardWillHide(_:)), name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil);

self.textWillSearch.delegate = self
self.textSkillSearch.delegate = self
```

}

2. keyboard event and text view event.

////

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) {
    if textView == textWillSearch {
        self.view.frame.origin.y = -130
    }
 }

func textViewDidEndEditing(textView: UITextView) {
    self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
}

func keyboardWillHide(sender: NSNotification) {
    self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
}

deinit {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}

// called when 'return' key pressed. return NO to ignore.
func textViewShouldEndEditing(textView: UITextView) -> Bool {
    textView.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}

// called when users tap out of textfield
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should track textView isActive on your controller and when `keyboardWillShow:` run, if textView you want active you will change constraint if not you return. You can check it is `isFirstResponder()`or you can use `UITextViewDelegate` with two function:

`textViewShouldBeginEditing`

and `textViewShouldEndEditing`.

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

You can override method `keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification)` and inside it make a check who is firstResponder like this:

```
if descriptionTextView.isFirstResponder {
// do your staff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call this function in your notifications.

```
@objc func keyboardWillAppear(notification: NSNotification)
{
    let keyFrame = notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! CGRect
    let keyY:CGFloat = keyFrame.origin.y
    textView.frame.origin.y = keyY - textView.frame.height
}

@objc func hideKeyboard()
{
    textView.frame.origin.y = whatever you want
}
```